# After testing with "cypress run" 276 out of 332 tests ended with "Skipped"

Tags: node.js, npm, cypress

After 5 hours, my tests were over and most of the tests were skipped. What could be the reason for this?

Here is a piece of logs and a screenshot:

> 12 info lifecycle cypress-dynamic-data@1.0.0~cypress:run: Failed to
> exec cypress:run script 13 verbose stack Error:
> cypress-dynamic-data@1.0.0 cypress:run: `cypress run` 13 verbose stack
> Exit status 25 13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.
> (C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
> 13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20) 13
> verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
> 13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20) 13
> verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16) 13
> verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
> (internal/child_process.js:288:5) 14 verbose pkgid
> cypress-dynamic-data@1.0.0 15 verbose cwd
> C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\xyz\cypress-dynamic-data 16 verbose Windows_NT
> 10.0.19041 17 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run"
> "cypress:run" 18 verbose node v14.15.0 19 verbose npm  v6.14.8 20
> error code ELIFECYCLE 21 error errno 25 22 error
> cypress-dynamic-data@1.0.0 cypress:run: `cypress run` 22 error Exit
> status 25 23 error Failed at the cypress-dynamic-data@1.0.0
> cypress:run script. 23 error This is probably not a problem with npm.
> There is likely additional logging output above. 24 verbose exit [ 25,
> true ]

[image]

Comment: Pls add screenshot of some of the skipped tests end logs

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what went wrong. The domain on I was hitting stopped responding.